# How can I count no.of strings executed

Tags: python, string

```
for fizzbuzz in range(1,500):
if (fizzbuzz % 3==0 and fizzbuzz % 5==0:
  print(fizzbuzz)
else:
  print(not divisible)
```

Now, how to see how many fizzbuzz's are there with exact count.

Comment: Show us attempt you have tried for this

Comment: Idk, am still learning, I used count(fizzbuzz),searched online and used like message.count(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to update a counter. Adding to the code you've shown and properly indenting:

```
c = 0

for fizzbuzz in range(1,500):
  if (fizzbuzz % 3==0 and fizzbuzz % 5==0:
    print(fizzbuzz)
    c += 1
  else:
    print(not divisible)

print(c)
```

Of course, you could also just increment your range by `15`, and start with `15`:

```
c = 0

for i in range(15, 500, 15):
  print(fizzbuzz)
  c += 1

print(c)
```